# EF code first, Deep Copy of complex entity, "ID is part of objects key info and cannot be modified" - error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deep-copy

I am attempting to write a generic Entity Framework code first Copy routine.
This routine copies the source properties, creates new child entities, copies references to lookup entities and copies child collections.
It appears to work. 
On inspection of the created entity all the child, lookups and collections are all present, but when I call the DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() I get the following error;

```
'The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. '
```

On investigation it appears that the error is being raised by the newly created child entities (not the newly created root entity/parent)

Here is the routine with the relevant section populated (if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildAttribute)));)

```
    public static void CloneCopy<T>( T original, object destination) where T : class
    {
        var dest = destination as T;

        if (dest == null)
            throw new Exception("destination does not match source type");


        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite) continue;

                if (propertyInfo.Name.Equals("ID")) continue;

                if (propertyInfo.Name.EndsWith("ID") && propertyInfo.Name.Length > 2) continue;

                var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(destination, pv, null);
            }
            else
            {

                //dont need to copy parent entity
                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityParentAttribute)))
                ...

                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityLookupAttribute)))
                ...

                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityInterfaceLookupAttribute)))
            ...


                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildAttribute)))
                {
                    dynamic source = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                    var target = propertyInfo.GetValue(dest, null);
                    if (source == null) return;

                    if (target == null)
                    {
                        var t = source.GetType();
                        target = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    }

                    source.CopyMeToProvidedEntity(target);

                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dest, target, null);
                }

                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildCollectionAttribute)))
                ...

            }
        }

    }
```

So they can copy themselves, all of my entities have the method CopyMeToProvidedEntity(target) defined on their base class and overridden on their implementation. It looks like this and calls the above function;

```
    public override void CopyMeToProvidedEntity(object destination)
    {
        CloneUtil.CloneCopy(this, destination);
    }
```

I also further define the Associations on my entities with Additional Attributes (EntityParent, EntityLookup, EntityChild, EntityChildCollection) of my own creation.

I am kind of stuck. The copy routine ignores the ID's and never writes to them on the new entities. The ID is defined thusly;

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

so is always set to 0 on initialisation

Any help will be gratefully received

24/06/2017 - Added full CloneCopy routine

```
    public static void CloneCopy<T>( T original, object destination) where T : class
    {
        var dest = destination as T;

        if (dest == null)
            throw new Exception("destination does not match source type");

        //set cloning property so update triggers etc can be ignored
        ((IsCloneable)original).IsCloning = true;
        ((IsCloneable)dest).IsCloning = true;



        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            {
                if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite) continue;

                if (propertyInfo.Name.Equals("ID")) continue;

                if (propertyInfo.Name.EndsWith("ID") && propertyInfo.Name.Length > 2) continue;

                var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(destination, pv, null);
            }
            else
            {

                //Shouldn't need to do anything here as Entity Framework handles it
                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityParentAttribute)))
                {
                    //object pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                    //propertyInfo.SetValue(Destination, pv, null);
                }

                //Just put the entity here
                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityLookupAttribute)))
                {
                    var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dest, pv, null);
                }

                //Just put the entity here
                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityInterfaceLookupAttribute)))
                {
                    var pv = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dest, pv, null);
                }

                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildAttribute)))
                {
                    dynamic source = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null);
                    var target = propertyInfo.GetValue(dest, null);
                    if (source == null) return;

                    if (target == null)
                    {
                        var t = source.GetType();
                        target = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    }

                    source.CopyMeToProvidedEntity(target);

                    propertyInfo.SetValue(dest, target, null);
                }

                if (dest.PropertyHasCustomAttribute(propertyInfo.Name, typeof(EntityChildCollectionAttribute)))
                {
                    var source = propertyInfo.GetValue(original, null) as IList;
                    var target = propertyInfo.GetValue(dest, null) as IList;
                    foreach (dynamic sourceEntity in source)
                    {
                        var found = false;
                        object targetEntity = null;

                        foreach (dynamic tEntity in target)
                        {
                            if (sourceEntity.IdentityGuid != tEntity.IdentityGuid) continue;
                            found = true;
                            targetEntity = tEntity;
                            break;
                        }

                        if (!found)
                        {
                            var b = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                            targetEntity = Activator.CreateInstance(b);
                        }

                        sourceEntity.CopyMeToProvidedEntity(targetEntity);

                        if (!found)
                        {
                            target.Add(targetEntity);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        ((IsCloneable)original).IsCloning = false;
        ((IsCloneable)dest).IsCloning = false;
    }
```

27/06/2017 - I've kind of located what the problem was

I have a property on the base class of my entities to aid with the pairing of cloned entities to their originators;

```
    private string _identityGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [Browsable(false)]
    [NotMapped]

    public virtual string IdentityGuid
    {
        get { return _identityGuid; }
        set { CheckPropertyChanged(ref _identityGuid, value); }
    }
```

If this property is copied I get the ID error in the Question Title...
I have no idea why this is so. 
I've renamed it "Peter" just incase it's some EF automatic thing.

To fix I've conditionally excluded any properties named "IdentityGuid" and the copy routine now works and the copy can be saved to the database.

If anybody can explain what is wrong with this property I would be most grateful :)

Comment: Is the double `if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace == "System" || propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)` part of your original code? Because it will render the `else` completely useless ;)

Comment: I think you have to provide the code in place of the `...` for parent, lookup, interface and childcollection. Also best find a minimal example of concrete entity data, where the problem occurs.

Comment: The double if statement is not in my original code.

I have added the full clone copy routine.I will look to create an example project soon :)

Comment: `CheckPropertyChanged` is probably registering the change with the underlying `ObjectContext` instance. If you do not want to map or track it then make it an auto-property instead or do the assignment directly in the `set`.

Comment: I still can't work out why the IdentityGuid property is triggering the ID error. Is there a way of viewing the entity graph and finding the entity that is causing the error? Some kind of Entity framework inspector? When I view detail on the exception it doesn't give anything away!

Comment: The exception is being thrown when I call the DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() function. its an InvalidOperationException so I can't examine the DbEntityValidationException that would normally be thrown by SaveChanges()

Answer (score 1):

I do not often see a need to use reflection for this task as it is not likely that you will want to clone just any entities. Usually what you want to clone is known and there is a business use case for it. If you later determine that is the case you could do the following.

1. Turn Lazy Loading off on the `DbContext` instance if it is not off already.
2. Retrieve the root entity that you want to clone

   - `Include` statements to get all compositions that you want to include in the clone as well.
   - Do not retrieve entities that you will not clone but have a relation to, instead rely that the FK will take care of that for you.
   - In the retrieval statement us `AsNoTracking`
3. Set the keys of the root entity and all its compositions to their default state as if the entity were new.
4. `Add` the root entity to the `DbContext`
5. Save changes.

Overly simplified sample code:

```
var root = dbContext.TypeA
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => someCondition)
        .Include(x => composititions)
        .SingleOrDefault();
root.Key = 0; // reset key
root.Comps.ForEach(comp => comp.Key = 0); // reset composition keys
dbContext.TypeA.Add(root);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for replying. Your method relies on the entity graph being copied having been previously propagated to the datastore. This isn't always the case in my system as I have fairly complex "documents" with sub entities that need to be copied by the user within the document before saving. I can already manually/explicitly copy entities and have to do this quite often. I'm writing a generic routine to handle this for me. On inspection of the created copy, everything looks correct

Comment: All the ID keys are set correctly to 0 and as far as I can work out are never touched. When calling the routine you have to manually create a fresh new root entity to copy to and then add it to the context...

Comment: @Lance - You should not have to do that, the error is that an entity that you retrieved is being tracked by the DbContext. You can either detach those entity/ies or you can dispose and create a new DbContext instance and attach your entity root to that instance.

Comment: I'm confused. when I copy an entity, the routine is copying the entities properties (except the ID's) to a freshly newed entity, any children are created using the  var t = source.GetType();
                            target = Activator.CreateInstance(t); I'm not sure how they are being tracked... though somehow they are

Comment: @Lance - it could be that you are copying a reference type from one entity to the one you are copying to and that reference type is a tracked entity. By copy I mean a shallow copy of just the pointer to that reference type. This could also be the case for a collection (ie. one to many or many to many) where the code copies the pointer to the collection which points to an existing/tracked list of entities.

Comment: Ok I've worked it out, but I don't know why. I have a [NotMapped] property called IdentityGuid

        //To pair copies with their originals
        private string _identityGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        [Browsable(false)]
        [NotMapped]
        
        public virtual string IdentityGuid
        {
            get { return _identityGuid; }
            set { CheckPropertyChanged(ref _identityGuid, value); }
        }

If the routine copies this I get the ID error. I thought it was the name, but renaming it "Peter" made no difference. Any ideas why?